# Can we use PV^y = constant equation for irreversible adiabatic processes?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

Example: One mole of monoatomic gas expands at initial temperature $T$ at constant external pressure of $\pu{1atm}$ from $\pu{1L}$ to $\pu{2L}$. 
To find final temperature, why can't we use $PV^y$ or $TV^{y-1} = \text{constant}$?
I am able to get final Temperature using $W+U=0$.

Comment: Imagine reversible expansion against a piston, versus irreversible expansion to another contained with vacuum. Is there any difference in W for the former and for the latter ? Se also [Joule-Thompson efect ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)

Comment: It is extremely difficult to carry out any process in an irreversible way.

Comment: @Maurice Why ? It is extremely easy. It is any process where we cannot consider the system being in equilibrium in every moment. What is extremely difficult to manage is a reversible process.

Comment: @ Poutnik. To transform a gas sample irreversibly, you have to adapt the inner pressure to the outer pressure during the whole transformation. You also have to equalize the temperature of the inner gas and the temperature of the surroundings. That is not easy to carry out.

Comment: Sure, I fully agree, but I want to point out you switched the meanings of the terms reversible and irreversible, so where you say irreversibly should be reversibly.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_(thermodynamics):  "Throughout the entire reversible process, the system is in thermodynamic equilibrium with its surroundings."..."Since it would take an infinite amount of time for the reversible process to finish, perfectly reversible processes are impossible."

Comment: Your original equation depends on the ideal gas law being satisfied, and the ideal gas law is not satisfied in an irreversible process (exxcept in the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states).  The ideal gas law is satisfied only at thermodynamic equilibrium (or in a reversible process, which is comprised of a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states).